# Xampp OS X 5.5.37 unable to remote access

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I just upgrade xampp 5.5.37 for MariaDB but I cannot set up remote access to my htdocs.
in this new version, the httpd-xampp.conf, I can not find these line:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    #Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solve my issue:

find httpd.conf make change as follow:

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

    AllowOverride All

    # Require local # comment this out and add 
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

find httpd-xampp.conf if you want to allow phpmyadmin, then change follow:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    #Require local
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

If this does not work, meaning that the problem is router or firewall.
As i'm not an expert, I don't know this change will affect the security risk!

Comment: Working great. Thanks